# Extract data from text file to "String only" csv with python

Tags: python, csv, parsing

I am trying to extract data from a text file into a csv sheet.
I am using this:

```
fileOutput = open(outputFolder + '/' + outputfile, mode='w+', newline='', encoding='utf-8')
file_writer = csv.writer(fileOutput, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
```

However, when I have a value like "0009", it's parsed as "9" in csv.
My question is:
Is there a way I can force all values to be parsed as strings to get the data as it is?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The CSV writer includes the leading 0s if you pass the value as a string, but not if you've already converted the value to an integer.

```py
writer.writerow([int('0009')]) # writes "9" to the file
writer.writerow(['0009']) # writes "0009" to the file
```

When you pass it an integer, it has no way of knowing how many leading zeros there were in the original text - that information has already been discarded. You need to look at the code that's extracting your data from the original text file, and keep that code from doing a conversion to integer.

Comment: Hello! There's no conversion in my code because I have different values of phrases and numbers. it's just when it comes to numbers, they are treated as int in CSV. so I wanted to know if there's a way to make all of them treated as a string.

Comment: Can you show what the code that reads the text file looks like, and the code that actually writes to the CSV (by file_writer.writerow or whatever)? You'll have to make sure you're getting strings from the text file and passing them as strings to the writer, and then it should work without any extra settings. It seems like there must be something along the way that is parsing the data from the text file as a number, or else the CSV writer would already be including the leading zeros like you want.